# PHP - undefined offset

Tags: php, undefined, offset

This code below has Undefined offset error on line 5. 
I don't know why this appears, I'm fighting with this for about an hour. 
It says it's in a line where for is, but as I see syntax is correct :/

```
<?php
function palindrom($broj) {
    $brojniz=str_split($broj);
    for ($x=0; $x<3; $x++) {
        if ($brojniz[$x] != $brojniz[5-$x]) {return;}
    }
    return($broj);
}

$n=100;
$m=$n;
while ($n<1000) {
    while ($m<1000) {
    $br=$m*$n;
    palindrom($br);
    ++$m;
    }
    $m=100;
    ++$n;
}
?>
```

Comment: You need to add check if the `key`s exists in the array.

Comment: They do exist because $br is 6 figures number

Comment: Then print them and see if they really present.

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It isn't 6 figures number. Problem solved! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but as I see syntax is correct

Yes, the syntax is correct.  But the runtime values are not.  This syntax is also correct, but will produce an error:

```
$x = 1 / 0;
```

The line in question is indexing an array:

```
if ($brojniz[$x] != $brojniz[5-$x])
```

And the value `$x` goes from 0-2 in that loop.  So you're indexing as such:

```
if ($brojniz[0] != $brojniz[5])
if ($brojniz[1] != $brojniz[4])
if ($brojniz[2] != $brojniz[3])
```

Does that array go from 0-5?  If not, then you're referencing an undefined index.

Comment: It goes from 0-5 because $br is 6 character number, so when I turn that string into an array it should go from 0-5

Comment: @HrvojeSpajić: Are you sure about that?  The first call to the function is with `100*100` which is `10000`.  That's five digits.  When you debug this, what is the value of `$br` when the error happens?

Comment: You are right! It isn't 5 digit number, problem solved. Thank you!